# Perl: How to make hash of hash where keys come from an array

Tags: perl, perl-hash

I want to make a hash of hash using the structure of an array. Each array element should be a subkey of the preceding array element. For example using the following arrays:

```
@array1 = ("animal","dog","sparky");
@array2 = ("animal","cat","felix");
@array3 = ("animal","bird","penguin","skipper");
```

I want to make a hash that is structured like this:

$hash{"animal"}{"dog"}{"sparky"} = 1;

```
%hash = ( 
  "animal" => { 
     "dog" => {
         "sparky" => "1", 
      }, 
     "cat" => {
         "felix" => "1", 
      }, 
     "bird" => {
         "penguin" => {
             "skippy" => "1", 
          }, 
      }, 
  }, 
);
```

The arrays will not always have the same number of elements. But it should build the structure just the same.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason your own attempt to code this did not work?

Comment: This is sounding like an XY problem to me. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sounding like an XY problem to me - I'm very suspicious that you've 3 separate, numbered arrays.

But I'll answer on the off chance you're seeing a more general case - the trick to doing this sort of thing is using a hash reference to traverse and reset.

```
    use Data::Dumper;
    my %hash; 
    my @array1 = ("animal","bird","penguin","skipper");
    my $cursor = \%hash; 
    
    foreach my $element (  @array1 ) {  
       $cursor -> {$element} //= {};
       $cursor = $cursor -> {$element};
    }
    $cursor = 1; 

    print Dumper \%hash;
```

So we walk down your data structure; and create a subelement - using `//=` to create a new subhash if - and only if - there isn't one defined already.

So for your whole set:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
my %hash;
my @array1 = ( "animal", "dog",  "sparky" );
my @array2 = ( "animal", "cat",  "felix" );
my @array3 = ( "animal", "bird", "penguin", "skipper" );

my $cursor = \%hash;

foreach my $array ( \@array1, \@array2, \@array3 ) {
    foreach my $element (@$array) {
        $cursor->{$element} //= {};
        $cursor = $cursor->{$element};
    }
    $cursor = 1;
    $cursor = \%hash;
}
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Now note - this doesn't have quite the desired outcome, in that we create empty hashes to populate your structure with. So the bottom level is `{}` - an empty hash - not the `1` you're seeking.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'animal' => {
                        'dog' => {
                                   'sparky' => {}
                                 },
                        'bird' => {
                                    'penguin' => {
                                                   'skipper' => {}
                                                 }
                                  },
                        'cat' => {
                                   'felix' => {}
                                 }
                      }
        };
```

But hopefully this gives you an idea how the problem can be solved?

It's worth looking at what autovivification is, and what it's doing - usually it's helpful, but for building this sort of data structure it may not be. We've explicitly created an empty subhash below each of your keys - but only if one doesn't exist already.

So in order to accomplish what you're trying to do - we actually need to handle the last element differently - we're not trying to create and empty subhash, we're attempting to set a value.

Thus:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
my %hash;
my @array1 = ( "animal", "dog",  "sparky" );
my @array2 = ( "animal", "cat",  "felix" );
my @array3 = ( "animal", "bird", "penguin", "skipper" );

my $cursor = \%hash;

foreach my $array ( \@array1, \@array2, \@array3 ) {
    # remove the last value from the array
    my $last =  pop @$array;
    foreach my $element (@$array) {
        $cursor->{$element} //= {};
        $cursor = $cursor->{$element};
    }
    #set the last value to be '1' instead of a subhash.
    #Otherwise it'll be created by the //= line above, and be an empty hash. 
    $cursor -> {$last} = 1;
    $cursor  = \%hash;
}
print Dumper \%hash;
```

This gives us the desired result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'animal' => {
                        'dog' => {
                                   'sparky' => 1
                                 },
                        'bird' => {
                                    'penguin' => {
                                                   'skipper' => 1
                                                 }
                                  },
                        'cat' => {
                                   'felix' => 1
                                 }
                      }
```

Or you can look at `Data::Diver` which approximately accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: This worked! I didn't know conceptually how to deal with the key names (//=). One more question, how can assign an array instead of "1". Instead of $cursor -> {$last} = 1; I want to assign an array called @values.

Comment: `$cursor -> {$last} = \@values;`. (Note - if you do this by reference, you need to ensure you don't reuse your `@values` in in a different iteration of the loop)